# "Google" python style script not working

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I'm trying to use the [Google python indentation script](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google_python_style.vim), but it's not working for me.  I want it to indent as follows:

```
very_long_function_name(
    first_param,
```

I pasted its text onto the end of [this vim script:](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3003) and put it into `~/.vim/indent/python.vim`.  Not sure why it's not working.

---

Edit: FIXED.

I modified the indent file as follows:

```
function GetGooglePythonIndent(lnum)
  " Indent inside parens.
  " Align with the open paren unless it is at the end of the line.
  " E.g.
  "   open_paren_not_at_EOL(100,
  "                         (200,
  "                          300),
  "                         400)
  "   open_paren_at_EOL(
  "       100, 200, 300, 400)
  call cursor(a:lnum, 1)
  let [par_line, par_col] = searchpairpos('(\|{\|\[', '', ')\|}\|\]', 'bW',
        \ "line('.') < " . (a:lnum - s:maxoff) . " ? dummy :"
        \ . " synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')"
        \ . " =~ '\\(Comment\\|String\\)$'")
  echo par_line par_col
  if par_line > 0
    call cursor(par_line, 1)
    if par_col != col("$") - 1
      return par_col
    else
      return indent(par_line) + &sw " FIXED HERE. FIXED BY ADDING THIS LINE
    endif
  endif

  " Delegate the rest to the original function.
  return GetPythonIndent(a:lnum)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by modifying the script and adding a missing line.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing `filetype indent on` from your .vimrc.

Comment: Thanks, but typing `:filetype` gives `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`

Comment: ok, maybe try making a backup of your current .vimrc and make an empty .vimrc for testing, to see if it works then. leave only filetype indent on in it. Also, is there any reason you are using an autocommand for loading the script?

Comment: @Uku: I am now using an empty .vimrc except for "filetype plugin indent on" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: ok, two (probably stupid) questions first: is your file ending with *.py? are you sure you are using def function( ? it does not appear in your example. Also, post the output of vim --version . Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @Uku: `set filetype` returns `filetype=python`; Version 7.3; python 2.7

Comment: I am pressing enter after "def ajdsflkajsldkfjkajsldfj(" and the indent is not on column 4, but is lined up with the "(".

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I should be getting to bed, but I just checked and it sets it correctly for me. Good luck :)

Comment: @Uku: Thanks again for bearing with me. I debugged it for myself and will show my solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to copy the script to `~/.vim/after/indent/python.vim` as the built-in python indent script overridden the one I added to `~/.vim/indent/python.vim`.

I was able to see the loaded order by `:scriptnames` command.