# Indent continuation lines differently depending on whether they start or not on a new line

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation, auto-indent

I'm trying to get vim to indent continuation lines starting on a new line this way:

```
def foo
  open_paren_at_EOL(
      100, 200)

  a = {
      :foo => 1,
  }
end
```

Vim 7.3's default indentation [1] for those lines looks like this:

```
def foo
  open_paren_at_EOL(
    100, 200)

  a = {
    :foo => 1,
  }
end
```

I have tried multiple cino= values and I even tried adapting the .vim script from [2] but with no success.

My .vimrc is here:

https://github.com/slnc/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Thanks!

- [1] https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/master/indent/ruby.vim
- [2] ["Google" python style script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696837/google-python-style-script-not-working)

Comment: Would also love this, but I lack the skill to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do to get this kind of indenting is to find out which areas of the `GetRubyIndent` function are relevant to these continuations and increase the return values. For the example you gave, this seems to do the job:

```
diff --git a/indent/ruby.vim b/indent/ruby.vim
index 05c1e85..6f51cf2 100644
--- a/indent/ruby.vim
+++ b/indent/ruby.vim
@@ -368,7 +368,7 @@ function GetRubyIndent(...)

  " If the previous line ended with a block opening, add a level of indent.
  if s:Match(lnum, s:block_regex)
-    return indent(s:GetMSL(lnum)) + &sw
+    return indent(s:GetMSL(lnum)) + &sw * 2
  endif

  " If the previous line ended with the "*" of a splat, add a level of indent
@@ -383,7 +383,7 @@ function GetRubyIndent(...)
    if open.pos != -1
      if open.type == '(' && searchpair('(', '', ')', 'bW', s:skip_expr) > 0
        if col('.') + 1 == col('$')
-          return ind + &sw
+          return ind + &sw * 2
        else
          return virtcol('.')
        endif
```

I'm not entirely sure if this won't break anything else, but it seems like a safe change to me. If you find cases that don't indent the way you want, you could just fix it the hard way: search for `return` within the limits of the function, then increase the indentation that is returned by one more `&shiftwidth` (or `&sw`). Check if it works, and if it doesn't, undo and then move on to the next `return`, until you actually find it.

You could fork `vim-ruby`, or you could just copy the `indent/ruby.vim` file to `~/.vim/indent/ruby.vim` and change it as you wish. It should have priority over the bundled `indent/ruby.vim`.

If you're looking for a completely unobtrusive solution, that would be difficult. Theoretically, you could
override the `GetRubyIndent` function as an indenter by using `setlocal indentexpr=CustomGetRubyIndent(v:lnum)`, and then define a `CustomGetRubyIndent` function, which implements your behaviour in particular cases only and delegates to `GetRubyIndent`. I wouldn't recommend going that far, though, it could get rather messy.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it works perfectly. You don't know how many keystrokes you are saving me now :)